# Speech rate detection in python

Tags: audio

I need to detect the speech rate (speed of spoken words) an a audio file. Most of codes available including pyaudioanalysis etc provide sampling rate, silence detection, or even emotion detection.
The need is I want to know how fast speaker is speaking. Can anyone suggest some code or technique please.

Comment: How about doing speech to text and then counting number of words per unit of time?

Comment: Thanks for reply.. but in a speech there can be silence too..

Comment: ... and that's where you have voice activity detector, assuming that silence is not counted against the speech rate.

Comment: I will give it a try... But I assume this is a new thing, there must have been done already on this by this large community and some reliable code must be available

Comment: SO isn't a community that recommends tools or libraries. That being said, if you were to measure articulation rate, you'd have an easier job finding something with your favorite search engine.

Comment: (have you get offended!) I googled it.. as exact results were not found (this may happen when people use different terms for the task in hand). So wondering if someone knows a same or similar thing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215070/discussion-between-lukasz-tracewski-and-sandeep-bhutani).

Answer (score 1):

I worked with speech to text but there are 2 main problems

1. Not all the words are correct that is produced by the engine.
2. There can be long pauses in between the text that doesn't help for the detection of speech rate.

I was working with PRAAT software, and there is an extension for this in python(https://github.com/YannickJadoul/Parselmouth). A detailed explanation of the procedure is given here

There is an option for detection of speech rate with the script(https://sites.google.com/site/speechrate/Home/praat-script-syllable-nuclei-v2). Using Parselmouth we can run the script. In case if you are ok with using PRAAT software here is a step by step analysis https://sites.google.com/site/speechrate/Home/tutorial.

The script returns no of syllables, no of pauses, duration, speech rate, articulation rate, ASD(speaking_time/no_of_syllables).

for reference paper-`https://www.researchgate.net/publication/24274554_Praat_script_to_detect_syllable_nuclei_and_measure_speech_rate_automatically`

check this https://github.com/Shahabks/myprosody, this could work even.

Hope this helps.